# $5^{\frac 1 2 -r}=(\frac x 3) ^{2r-1}$, $\pm$ solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$5^{\frac 1 2 -r}=(\frac x 3) ^{2r-1}$$

$$=> \dfrac 1 {5^{r-\frac 1 2}} = (\frac {x^2} {3^2})^{r-\frac 1 2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (*)$$ 
$$=> (\dfrac 9 5)^{r-\frac 1 2} =(x^2)^{r-\frac 1 2}$$
$$=> x = \pm \dfrac {3\sqrt 5} 5$$

But if we take (*) as
$$=> \dfrac 1 {(5^{\frac 1 2})^{2r-1}} = (\frac {x} {3})^{2r-1}$$
This $-$ sign no longer occurs.

So does $-\dfrac {3\sqrt 5} 5$ counts as a solution?
Which method in the above is more recommendable when I approach a problem like this?

This is a small part of a question I am solving at the moment
and the solution paper only states the positive value of this $x$.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is $r$ an integer?

Comment: @Dr.MV oops I should've added that. This equation comes from the expansion of $\dfrac {4x} {(9-4x^2)^{\frac 3 2}}$. The integer $r$ represents limit from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: If $r$ is an integer, then $2r-1$ is an odd integer. If $x$ is negative, then so is $x/3$, and so is any odd power of $x/3$. So what happens, then, when you look back at the original equation?

Comment: You need $r\neq \frac12$ because otherwise all $x$ is solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you!

Comment: So, if you understand how it goes now, you can write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But..!! you wouldn't want the reputation points? It is you who gave the right answer afterall. If you just copy paste what you wrote I will select it as a solution. :D Or maybe this is too simple for you. In that case I guess I will write it up..